# MacBook Pro + Dell C2422HE - Dell is mirroring

Tags: macos

I connected my dual Dell C2422HE monitor to my USB-C port, but my Mac is recognizing both monitors as a single one! Take a look:
[image]

Any ideas of what do I have to do so they work as individual displays?

Comment: What is the year of your MacBook Pro? Is the Mac Intel or Apple Silicon? This information would help determine how the displays could be connected as desired.

Comment: its the latest MacBook Pro with M2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macOS operating system cannot drive two individual displays from a single DisplayPort cable plugged into the Mac. You need an operating system such as Windows for that to work. With macOS, the displays mirror each other. In other words, macOS cannot do Multi-Stream Transport (MST).

---

### 2022 13" MacBook Pro Models with Apple M2

Choose one of the following.

- Plug one display to an USB-C port. The other will have to connected through a DisplayLink (or similar) adaptor.
- Connect both displays through a DisplayLink (or similar) adaptor. Only one of the displays with require DisplayLink.
- Connect through an appropriate DisplayLink capable dock.

---

### 2023 14" and 16" MacBook Pro Models with Apple M2 Pro or Apple M2 Max

Choose one of the following.

- Plug each display into separate USB-C ports
- Plug one display in a USB-C port and the other into the HDMI port.
- Connect through an appropriate dock.